# Windows 7: enabling navigation of subfolders in pinned Start Menu folders

Tags: windows-7, start-menu, pinning

I'm just about to move from Windows XP to Windows 7, and I'm struggling with some of the interface changes.

In XP, I was able to throw a folder into`C:\Documents and Settings\username\Start Menu`and have it appear on the Start Menu, complete with the ability to navigate through subfolders. I've figured out how to pin a folder onto the Start Menu in Windows 7, which required a **[registry hack](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/8964-start-menu-pin-unpin-folder.html)**. However, I am unable to view the subfolders of the pinned folder without opening a new Windows Explorer window.

Is there any way to replicate the old XP behavior I'm used to?  I'd like to be only a single click away from these handful of application links and folders, since I use them all the time throughout the day.

Comment: Btw, you don't need to use a registry hack. All you need to do, I believe, is to drag a folder onto the start button, wait a second or two, wait for the start menu to open, drag it onto the start menu, and it'll get pinned. I may be wrong though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can drag a folder onto the start button, wait for it to pop up, drag to a spot in the pinned list, and drop it there.  It'll get pinned *but* you won't be able to browse it as a menu.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have found to do this is using the included **mklink** utility.

Open a terminal in **%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu** and enter the command:

```
mklink /D <Name to Pin as> <Target folder to pin>
```

For example, to pin Program Files, type:

```
mklink /D "Program Files" "%ProgramFiles%"
```

However, this method will still require you to open the **All Programs** menu before you can see the folder. Directly browsing a folder from the start menu does not seem possible.

As an alternative, you could try making a toolbar of the folder in your taskbar.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch back to a previous Windows version Start Menu. This is pretty spectacular:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/classicshell/